# Mismatching url from build_absolute_uri() issue : double slashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, path

I am trying to send a confirmation email with sendgrid, but when user click the link, it generated My Page not found error:

```
The current path,/confirm//confirm/, didn't match any of these.
```

This my views.py

```
message = Mail(
            from_email=settings.FROM_EMAIL,
            to_emails=sub.email,
            subject='Newsletter Confirmation',
            html_content='Thank you for signing up for my email newsletter! \
                Please complete the process by \
                <a href="{}/confirm/?email={}&conf_num={}"> clicking here to \
                confirm your registration</a>.'.format(request.build_absolute_uri('/confirm/'),
                                                    sub.email,
                                                    sub.conf_num))
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(settings.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
        response = sg.send(message)

def confirm(request):
    sub = Subscriber.objects.get(email=request.GET['email'])
    if sub.conf_num == request.GET['conf_num']:
        sub.confirmed = True
        sub.save()
        return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'email': sub.email, 'action': 'confirmed'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'email': sub.email, 'action': 'denied'})
```

app level urls.py:

```
  path('confirm/', views.confirm, name='confirm'),
  path('delete/', views.delete, name='delete'),
```

I know there must be the problem of `build_absolute_uri('/confirm/')` or the `confirm view`, I have tried different attempts by changing the url `build_absolute_uri('confirm/')` or `build_absolute_uri('')` but it still didn't match any URL.

Update:
I think it is the combined problem of `<a href="{}/confirm/?email={}&conf_num={}">` and `format(request.build_absolute_uri('/confirm/')` How can I adjust it so it wont cause the error of double slahses or double confirm?

Comment: Please try "<a href="{}?email={}&....."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result:

After I have changed it to `<a href="{}?email={}&conf_num={}">` and `format(request.build_absolute_uri('/confirm/')`, The error disappeared and it reached the url path that I want. Although I don't know why, it fixed my problem.